# How do I correct a misspelled tag?

Tags: support, tags, editing

A user has posted a question concerning a game.
The user seems to have created a tag with the name of the game, but it is misspelled.

How do I correct a misspelled tag that is in use?

The tag in question was [camibo](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camibo) which has been corrected to [cambio](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cambio)

Comment: What tag are you referring to? Please edit that into the question and a mod might be able to help.

Comment: I was referring to «cambio» written as «camibo». The misspelling has since been corrected. I now see that there is an «edit» link next to the tag - I hadn't seen that.

Comment: I added that information to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enough reputation to edit the tags of the question and make sure the tag is spelled correctly.

If a tag isn't used on any question, it's automatically deleted after 24 hours. See [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange.

As a demonstration, I've changed the [edit](/questions/tagged/edit) and [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) tags on your question to the more commonly used [editing](/questions/tagged/editing) and [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).